# Change the markup/detected-language of a file

Tags: vim

Is it possible to change the language that is detected in a `vim` file? For example, in TextMate, there is a language dropdown so that you can, for example, change a file from one language to another:

[image]

[image]

Also, sometimes I will have a json object in a python file, or some javascript in html, etc. I don't exact it to be able to mark-up each section properly, though it would be nice to be able to change the language-detected-formatted accordingly. Is this possible in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the language that is detected in a vim file? For example, in TextMate, there is a language dropdown so that you can, for example, change a file from one language to another:

Yes, it is! You can manually change the filetype (language) of files by setting the `filetype` option:

```
:set filetype=html
```

More information is available in the [documentation](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype).

> Also, sometimes I will have a json object in a python file, or some javascript in html, etc. I don't exact it to be able to mark-up each section properly, though it would be nice to be able to change the language-detected-formatted accordingly. Is this possible in vim?

I have not tried this myself, but there are some solutions in the Vim Tips Wiki: [Different syntax highlighting within regions of a file](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file)